# Home directory file auto deleted after upload laravel php

Tags: php

My system file deleted after few time upload.
I make changes in PHP.INI FILE

```
upload_tmp_dir =/var/sentora/temp
```

If i don't use this path, laravel give error temp directory not found.

But my main problem is after upload file in temp directory and I use move temp file function to store file to my donain directory in public folder but after few time this file will remove automatic.
I have no idea why this happened. `PHP` code running fine because php done it's job

```
Config
PHP5.6
UBUNTU 16.4 VPS
```